# Were the Moabites and Midianites ever enemies?

Tags: numbers

Were the Moabites and Midianites ever enemies?  We see them working as allies in Numbers 22:4, 7.

Comment: In Numbers where? Can you please provide a reference?

Answer (score 2):

According to Genesis 36:35, the Edomite king Hadad the son of Bedad attacked Midian in the field of Moab. The verse doesn't give any further information, but apparently there was a war between Midian and Moab, in which Hadad took Moab's side.